# Nested views in Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a rest API app with users and books with this URL structure (without routers):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', UserList.as_view(), name="user-list"),
    path('<uuid:id>/', UserDetail.as_view(), name="user-detail"),
    path('<uuid:id>/books/', BookList.as_view(), name="book-list"),
    path('<uuid:id>/books/<int:book_id>/', BookDetail.as_view(), name="book-detail"),
]
```

Serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    books = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many = True,
        queryset = Book.objects.all(),
        view_name = "book-detail",
    )
```

And generic views:

```
class BookList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'book_id'


class BookDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'book_id'
```

This doesn't work - I get the error:

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "book-detail"
```

I have tried changing the `lookup_field` and `view-name`, but I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this issue.

I looked into drf-nested-routers, but I'm hoping to find a solution without switching to routers if at all possible.

Update:

I'm using `book_id` as my primary key in the model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.ColossusUser', related_name="books", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Change `book_id` to **`pk`** in urls.py and `BookDetail` view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Hyperlinked URL field for more than one lookup field in a serializer of DRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038643/custom-hyperlinked-url-field-for-more-than-one-lookup-field-in-a-serializer-of-d)

Comment: I'm using `book_id` as my primary key - updated the code. Also, in searches the drf-nested-routers solutions didn't seem appropriate since I'm not using routers.

Comment: have you tried adding `lookup_field="book_id"` to the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` args?

Comment: @RishiG I tried, it does not seem to change the error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using

Comment: I think the problem might be the missing `uuid` kwarg. What happens if you change the `book-detail` view path to `path('books/<int:book_id>/', BookDetail.as_view(), name="book-detail")` (i.e. without the `uuid`)?

Comment: The idea was to try to achieve the nesting - but I've switched to routers, since that seems to be the generally recommended solution. Thanks.